# _Layout.cshtmlの状態を変化させたい

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

_Layout.cshtmlにリンクを作成しいます。
下図の場合、ホーム、詳細、連絡先それぞれをクリックしたとき、下図赤枠部分を現在表示しているページの文字を太字、サイズ変更等したいと考えています。

[image: サンプル]
html.ActionLink時にclassの追加等試したのですがうまく反映されません。
ご教示願います。

Comment: 基本的には`@class`を指定し、CSSかJavaScriptで効果を付ければよいと思いますがどのような記述を試されたのでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
リンク箇所は下記のように指定していました。
`@Html.ActionLink("詳細", "Detail", "home", new { @class = "headerLink" }, new { onclick = "selectedPage()" })`


onclickイベント後に色を変えようとしていたのですが、デバッグで追うとクリック直後は背景色が変わるのですが、ロード完了後に元に戻ってしまう。という状況です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

通常のリンクで別のページに移動した場合、すべてのDOM要素が再読み込みされますので遷移直前にJavaScriptで設定したスタイルは反映されません。

ですので`_Layout.cshtml`で現在表示中のアクションを判定して`@class`の値を制御してください。
コントローラー名およびアクション名は`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]`や`ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]`で参照できますし、コントローラーから明示的にモデルに指定すれば確実に判定できます。